# How do I register with Autofac a type that implements multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface, autofac

I have 2 classes that handle 2 different resources, they are **SettingsHandler** and **StorageHandler**.
Both have similar constructors:

```
public class StorageHandler
{
    private readonly IStorageConfig _config;
    private readonly ApiClient _apiClient;

    public StorageHandler(IStorageConfig config, ApiClient apiClient)
    {
        _config = config;
        _apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    /------- ! -------/
}

public class SettingsHandler
{
    private readonly ISettingsConfig _config;
    private readonly ApiClient _apiClient;

    public SettingsHandler(ISettingsConfig config, ApiClient apiClient)
    {
        _config = config;
        _apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    /------- ! -------/
```

}

Then I have my config like this:

```
public class Config: ISettingsConfig, IStorageConfig
{
}
```

In my **module** class I register the config file twice (more times if there are more interfaces) like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<Config>().As<ISettingsConfig>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Config>().As<IStorageConfig>().SingleInstance();
```

I was hoping that would work, but I am not sure I am doing this correctly.
Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register it like:

```
builder.RegisterType<Config>()
    .As<ISettingsConfig>()
    .As<IStorageConfig>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

but make sure you register `StorageHandler` and `SettingsHandler` too:

```
builder.RegisterType<StorageHandler>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<SettingsHandler>().AsSelf();
```

Once you built the container you should be able to Resolve `StorageHandler` and `SettingsHandler`:

```
var container = builder.Build();
var storageHandler = container.Resolve<StorageHandler>();
var settingsHandler = container.Resolve<SettingsHandler>();
```

## Note

It's also possible to call `AsImplementedInterfaces()` in case you have lots of interfaces on a class.